# Issue with trait and case class inheritance: scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

Below code gives me the error
**Method 'someMethod' overrides nothing**

But isn't case class C extending trait A? Why am I getting this error

```
trait A

trait B {
   def someMethod(req: A): Unit
}

case class C(i: Int, j: Int) extends A

object D extends B {
  override def someMethod(req: C) ={
     //some implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: I get the following error message: `(Note that A does not match C: class C is a subclass of trait A, but method parameter types must match exactly.)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can pass any value of type `A` to this method:

```
def someMethod(req: A)
```

But you can only pass values of type `C` to this method:

```
override def someMethod(req: C)
```

So the second version is not a full implementation of the first because it can't handle values of type `A` which are not values of type `C`. So the second version cannot `override` the first.

Possible solution:

```
override def someMethod(req: A) =
  req match {
    case C(i, j) => // Code
    case _ => // Error handling
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to Tim's answer, maybe you want something like this:

```scala
trait A
final case class C(i: Int, j: Int) extends A

trait B[T <: A] {
  def someMethod(req: T): Unit
}

object D extends B[C] {
  override def someMethod(req: C): Unit = {
     //some implementation
  }
}
```